# Creating a Hash with a method

Tags: ruby, methods, hash

I am having trouble creating a method to establish a new hash. I know that it is definitely easier just to declare the hash, however I need to create a method. Here is what I have so far and it keeps generating an error message.

```
def create_new(hash_name)
hash_name = Hash.new 

end
```

This should create and empty hash^

```
def add_item(hash_name, item_name, item_quantity)

hash_name[:item_name.to_sym] = item_quantity
end
```

I keep getting an error message on the above code^ I am trying to update this hash and add a new key value pair with a method

```
p create_new("grocery_list")
```

This creates a new empty hash^ however when I call it with the below code is says the hash is undefined

```
add_item(grocery_list, "pizza", "1")
 p grocery_list
```

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: And what's your expected behavior of `create_new`? Express it by (pseudo) code.

Comment: example.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `grocery_list' for main:Object (NameError) I am expecting create_new to create a hash with the name grocery_list and when I call on grocery list after the method call I can add new keys and values.

Comment: I see your use case. What you want is dynamically define methods or local variables. It's possible with Ruby, but certainly not at your level of skill.

Comment: @Aetherus I think OP's use case is merely to write a method that returns a hash; OP's use of `hash_hame` was merely a misunderstanding of the use of variables.  Be careful how you word your comments, your 'but certainly not at your level of skill' could be interpreted as hostile and condescending (though I realize that may not have been your intent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `create_new` method, you define a `hash_name` local variable. This variable does not exist anywhere but the body of your method. That's what seems to confuse you.

You could express better your intent with :

```
def create_new
  Hash.new
end

def add_item(hash, key, value)
   hash[key.to_sym] = value
end
```

In order to get to what you are trying to do, you will have to store the result of your method in some kind of variable in order to use it :

```
grocery_list = create_new # grocery_list is now a local variable

add_item(grocery_list, 'pizza', 1)
```

Comment: You're passing `'unused_variable'` to `create_new` but have defined `create_new` to take no arguments.  Are you referring to the original erroneous implementation?

Comment: oh yeah, gonna remove it. I wrote this before adding the refined code.

Answer (score 2):

You could also turn it into a class if you fancy.

```
class MyHash
  attr_reader :hash

  def initialize
    @hash = Hash.new
  end

  def [](key)
    self.hash[key]
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    self.hash[key.to_sym] = value
  end
end

grocery_list = MyHash.new
grocery_list['pizza'] = 1

> grocery_list.hash
=> {:pizza=>1}
```

Comment: This is an example of how one *would* create a class that (partially) imitated a hash, but let's be clear that doing this would not be a good idea, right?